# Why does getline(...) print on screen?

Tags: c++, input, cin, getline, clion

I'm trying to get (in C++) some input from keyboard which I want to store for later use. This is just a simplified version of the code I'm working on, but it reproduces the same behavior:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    std::string line;

    std::cout << "> ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    return 0;
}
```

`getline` correctly reads the input from stdin, but the input gets printed immediately after on a new line. Also, the white space after the `>` character is ignored when reading my input, but printed after. Something like:

```
>hi
> hi
```

Why does this happen? How can I avoid it?

I'm on Windows 10, using CLion 2016.1 (this happens on CLion's console).

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Are you running the code from the compiler?

Comment: You probably need to flush the output to ensure it appears when you want it to appear, otherwise the time of printing is implementation-defined.

Comment: [Cannot](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c803cd4281ed0c9) [reproduce](http://ideone.com/7XV0UM) [this](http://imgur.com/AvAyaUB) [behaviour](http://imgur.com/2BjuFCc).

Comment: @underscore_d - there's no need to flush the output. The standard streams are synchronized, for exactly this purpose, so when the program looks for input from `std::cin` it first flushes `std::cout` to display the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clion will do that if it is run in the built in console, however if run in the windows console it should not happen.

> How can I avoid it?

The easiest way for this to be done is to run it in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen?

Probably because of buffering of the output.

> How can I avoid it?

By having what should be printed be printed before calling `getline()` by using `std::cout << "> " << std::flush;` instead of `std::cout << "> ";`.

Comment: There's no need to flush standard output here. Reading from `std::cin` flushes standard output so that prompts show up before waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use std::cin? The strange behavior is probably because of your platform.

You have an `std::cout` followed by the `getline()` function. Some of the behavior from `getline` might be ever so slightly differently defined depending on the compiler you are using. Some may not be able to reproduce your behavior.

Essentially, in the traditional C++ style of keyboard I/O most people use a call to `std::endl` after most inputs or outputs. `endl` has within it an automatic call to `flush()` in order to flush the standard buffer. However, the `getline()` function is a holdover from the C language. In C, it's common to have to repeatedly use the `flush()` command to get the desired output you are looking for. This is one of the reasons why it's better to stick as best as you can to either C style output or C++ style output.

Why can't you use the `std::cin`? You could follow that up with an `endl` and everything should be well behaved after that.

Alternatively, you could get away with just calling a naked `endl` or a `flush()` to get the thing back in defined behavior land.

Is there a reason you need `getline()` specifically?